# Current city is nil;

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation

I am facing an strange problem am trying to get the current city, state and country using reverse geocodder. The state and country is fine but city is "nil". can anybody please help me out.

I am using following code :

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder*)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark*)place
{
    NSDictionary *addressDict = place.addressDictionary;
    self.currentCity = [addressDict objectForKey:(NSString*)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
    self.currentState = [addressDict objectForKey:(NSString*)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
    self.currentCountry = place.country;
    self.currentCountryCode = place.countryCode;
}
```

Comment: `NSLog("%@", (NSString*)kABPersonAddressCityKey);` and post the results.

Comment: Is your place definitely in some City?  Perhaps the reverse geocoder doesn't think so -- for example, is it in the middle of an ocean or desert?  Underneath, it just goes to google -- check their reverse geocode api directly with the same location.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, @CodaFi my key is proper as i am using same type of key for state and country. 

I am getting the state and country, I think it should give me the current location, and ofcource thats my current location.

Answer (score 2):

It uses Google maps, so go here to see how to check directly

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Check this with your location's lat/long:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

Do you get a city? If so, I recommend trying to capture the network traffic between your app and the reverse geocode servers.  One easy way to do this is to install Wireshark and then use the simulator and a custom location (supported in the latest simulator).